# Is there a bit-get function?

Tags: clojure, bit-manipulation, clojure-java-interop

Here's the behavior I want:

```
user> (bit-get 4 2)
> 1
```

I know this could super easily be done using `bit-test`, i.e.:

```
(defn bit-get [x n]
  (if (bit-test x n) 1 0))
```

But I'm curious if there's anything already out there. It might be kind of petty of me, but it just seems sub-optimal (however minimally so) to have to test whether something is `0` or `1`, and then return wehther or not it's `0` or `1` based on that test. So, I'd also be happy to hear of any ways to cut-out the middle man here, regardless of whether or not there's any previously-made `bit-get` function out there in the Clojure or Java world. Or perhaps I'm mistaken in the first place, and something about compilation or run-time optimization makes my `bit-get` function above not actually have to run the test just to return the value it's testing on? Or--seeing as I know next to nothing about timing/speed optimization involved in bitwise operators--perhaps it only seems sub-optimal, but is actually the fastest way to do it for some reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't say anything about optimization by the compiler (although I would be surprised if it was able to change a lot about your `bit-get` code), but - to take matters into your own hands - you could just rely on the lower-level logical operations `bit-shift-right` and `bit-and`, e.g.:

```
(defn bit-get [x n]
  (bit-and (bit-shift-right x n) 1))
```